# How to make an element not fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im currently working on header and I made a hamburger slide using javascript. The problem is when the bar slides to right , the title `<h2>` stays in his place. I hope there is a way to make it slide with the bar.

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
header {
  background: #ff5f88e6;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header h2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 24px 20px;
  left: -300px;
  top: 0
}

.toggle-btn {
  left: 340px;
  top: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.toggle-btn span {
  width: 45px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#sidebar.active {
  left: 0;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

#sidebar ul li {
  padding: 20px 24px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div id="sidebar">
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="show()">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Discusion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add Review</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <h2>"A Book can change the way you look"</h2>

</header>
</div>
```

that's what's before clicking on the hamburger
[image]
what happens after
[image]
I want the title to slide right so the user can read it

Comment: I presume you are *not* talking about the `<h2>`  in the code you show in your question?

Comment: PS: You're missing a `</div>` before the closing `</header>`

Comment: i just edited but the probleme is always the same

Comment: Again, are you showing the `<h2>` in your question @Karakopi? Seems likely not. Seems as what you think is "fixed" behavior is simply an absolute position element (your side bar) going on top of another and different "h2" in your body.

Comment: the thing is the `<h2>` in the header doesn't slide to right it stay fixed , and what i want is how to make it slide right the same time i click on `toggle-btn`

Comment: Ok i should have taken you for your word. If that "h2" is staying fixed then you likely have some errant css making h2 fixed. Problem with that idea is that the h2 wouldn't flow relative with the rest of the side bar to be at the correct vertical position. So im lost. ... Can you update your question with a "screen shot"?

Comment: i just updated it , as you can see the title stay undert the "toggle-btn" , even position absolute didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy option is to add a class to the header element as well when you move the menu to move the h2 element as well.

Edit: I removed the `active` class from the sidebar and just created a css selector to change the menu based on the parent `active` class. This selector `#header.active #sidebar`

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById('header').classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
header {
  background: #ff5f88e6;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
}

#header.active h2{
  margin-left: 300px;
}

header h2 {
  transition: 500ms all;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 24px 20px;
  left: -300px;
  top: 0;
  transition: 500ms all;
}

.toggle-btn {
  left: 340px;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.toggle-btn span {
  width: 45px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#header.active #sidebar {
  left: 0;
}

#sidebar ul li {
  padding: 20px 24px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="show()">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Discusion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add Review</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <h2>"A Book can change the way you look"</h2>
</header>
```

Comment: it works Thank you , but what if i have a lot of elements i can't go on every element and do the same thing , should i ?

Comment: The secret is, just add the class to the parent element and with css create a selector to have different behavior for all the elements you wish to change. Ex: you don't have to add a class to the sidebar in your example, you can achieve that using css selector based on the parent. Obs: I will update my answer

Comment: now i got it , thanks so much i've been looking for so long